# can't verify signature error occuring while updating my office 365

Tags: signature

while trying to update my pc with office 365 .can't verify signature message is popping up.
i tried uninstalling and installing the software .After performing sfc scan KB63363901 .that problem was solved. Is this the parmanent solution .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Considering that all references I can find on this KB article lead to one single non-MS resource (via multiple domains) my suspicion is that this isn't actually a valid, paid-for Office 365 license. As the solution apparently isn't provided by Microsoft, I'd suggest directing the question to whoever provided you the advise. If I'm in error and this is a paid license, MS Support should be able to provide you the answer.